# Too many initializer values in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently working on a C++ program and I cannot figure out how to get my array of characters to split up into 4 sub-arrays of characters. I have a 17 element array (1 for null) and I am trying to split it up into 4 smaller arrays of 4 elements each. I want to use strcpy_s but can't figure out how. And when I try setting it up as

```
char array[17]; //already set up as an array of characters)

char convert1[5] = {array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]};
```

It says I have too many initializes. If you have any ideas, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Please extract a minimal but complete example, as per the site guidelines. Your question is off-topic without one.

Comment: Thank you Amorandrom, I wasn't sure what he meant until you sent that

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? You should use std::vector or std::string in C++

Comment: I'm just trying to get a char array of 16 elements broken down into 4 smaller arrays. The first small array consisting of the first four elements, the second smaller array consisting of the next four elements and so on

Comment: I only have the first small array in the question but there is a convert2, convert3, and convert4 that are all the same dimensions as convert1

Comment: I guess the particular error can be solved by `char convert1[] = {array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]};`. But indeed C++ allows much nicer solutions!

Comment: This is the first time i have ever used stackoverflow so bear with me lol. I apologize for the confusion but if you have any suggestions to help you understand what I'm asking, please let me know

Comment: `char array[17]` is that initialized somewhere? You can't initialize the second line without giving some values to the char array[17] first. After that making 4 sub arrays is trivial with a function.

Comment: yes, it is initialized already. And i that's what i thought but i can't figure it out

Comment: i got it now! I'm an idiot lol thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `char array[17]` is initialized somewhere. I know that char arr[17] is filled in from 0-16 since arrays are 0-indexed. I can just use the following code to brute force it:

```
char arr1[4], arr2[4], arr3[4], arr4[4];

for(int i =0; i < 4; i++)
   arr1[i] = array[i];
for(int i =4; i < 8; i++)
   arr2[i] = array[i];
for(int i =8; i < 12; i++)
   arr3[i] = array[i];
for(int i =12; i < 16; i++)
   arr4[i] = array[i];
```

It's probably more efficient to use a function or a nested loop to pass in simpler structures but if you want a straightforward way to do that. This should work

Comment: Thank you! I figured out a way similar to this but I like your method better.

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you mind accepting my answer then? Since it solves your problem?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. However, this answer does not follow from the question, for which the question is at fault. The used approach to init one array with elements from another is sound, no need for loops. The error message probably comes from other code that isn't shown, hence the request for an MCVE.